# React Native undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.onPressButton.bind')

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, native

For so "onPress={this.onPressButton.bind(this)}" cause my application to fail?

What can I do to fix it. I believe its something to do with (this) becoming unbinded or something?

I have a component called Login being rendered:

```
export default class Login extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        id:'login'
    }
}

render() {
    return(
        <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style={style.container}>
            <View style={style.logoContainer}>
                <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" />
                <Image style={style.logo} source={require('../../image/Octocat.png')} />
                <Text style={style.logoText}> A Github app using React Native by{"\n"} Thomas Charlesworth</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={style.formContainer}>
                <LoginForm />
            </View>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
}
}
```

And a login form component:

```
export default class LoginForm extends Component {

onPressButton(){
    this.props.navigator.push({
        id: 'splash',
        passProps: {
        // Your Props
        }
    })
}

render() {
    return(
        <View style={style.container}>
            <TextInput 
                style={style.input} 
                placeholder="Username" 
                placeholderTextColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.5)"
                returnKeyType="next"
                autoCapitalize="none"
                autoCorrect={false}
                onSubmitEditing={()=> this.passwordInput.focus()}
            />
            <TextInput 
                style={style.input} 
                secureTextEntry 
                placeholder="Password" 
                placeholderTextColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.5)"
                returnKeyType="go"
                ref={(input) => this.passwordInput = input}
            />
            <TouchableOpacity 
                style={style.buttonContainer}
                onPress={this.onPressButton.bind(this)}
            > 
                <Text style={style.buttonText}>
                    LOGIN
                </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: did you define this method `onPressButton` ??

Comment: I made an edit please refer to that. I defined a method yes. Which stops the error, but when I click on the button, I get: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigator.push')

Answer (score 1):

Write it like this:

Pass a function from parent component:

```
<LoginForm update={this.update.bind(this)}>

navigate(data){
    this.props.navigator.push({data});
}
```

In Child component:

```
onPressButton(){
    let data = {
        /*data*/
    }
    this.props.navigate(data);
}
```

Comment: So what is the solution?

Comment: onPressButton(){
        this.props.navigator.push({
            id: 'splash'
        })
    } does not work

Comment: I'm not sure how to apply your answer. Because I'm using this: https://github.com/darkarmyIN/DARNNavigator

Comment: You're edit still doesn't solve the issue. It is still undefined.